# Visualize Traffic Light in OMNeT++

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I am new to OMNeT++, SUMO and Veins. Going over tutorials I am able to run a simple Veins project integrating Sumo and OMNeT++. I have two cars and 1 traffic light running over a cross section street. When I run my simulations, I can see two nodes (one for each car in SUMO) in OMNeT++ but not able to add a node for traffic light. It exists in SUMO but not in OMNeT++. Although I am able to access traffic light using TraCICommandInterface and get/set current status. I just want it to be visible in OMNeT++ simulator for visual purposes. Can any one guide me how to add a node for traffic light in OMNeT++ simulator.

Comment: Can you post some example code and your omnetpp.ini file?

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is a module in your simulation that reminds you of where the traffic light is, you can simply add any OMNeT++ module to your simulation and manually position it as appropriate.

If you want to be more fancy, you can add functionality to query TraCI at regular intervals to your module, to update its visual representation.

See the OMNeT++ Tic Toc tutorial for how to create custom modules, position them in the simulation, or change the visual representation of a module.